# Inno Setup image download

Tags: download, inno-setup, pascal

I'm working with Inno Setup Compiler (Pascal Scripting).
My form has an image object (TBitmapImage) and I'd like to supply a dynamic image obtained from the web URL. Is it possible to silently download an image (or other type of file) in Inno Setup scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually possible to download almost anything from the web using [InnoTools Downloader](http://sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50).

Answer (score 3):

I would write a small Win32 program that downloads a file from the Internet, such as

```
program dwnld;

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, WinInet;

const
  PARAM_USER_AGENT = 1;
  PARAM_URL = 2;
  PARAM_FILE_NAME = 3;

function DownloadFile(const UserAgent, URL, FileName: string): boolean;
const
  BUF_SIZE = 4096;
var
  hInet, hURL: HINTERNET;
  f: file;
  buf: PByte;
  amtc: cardinal;
  amti: integer;
begin
  result := false;
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(UserAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  try
    hURL := InternetOpenUrl(hInet, PChar(URL), nil, 0, 0, 0);
    try
      GetMem(buf, BUF_SIZE);
      try
        FileMode := fmOpenWrite;
        AssignFile(f, FileName);
        try
          Rewrite(f, 1);
          repeat
            InternetReadFile(hURL, buf, BUF_SIZE, amtc);
            BlockWrite(f, buf^, amtc, amti);
          until amtc = 0;
          result := true;
        finally
          CloseFile(f);
        end;
      finally
        FreeMem(buf);
      end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
  end;
end;

begin

  ExitCode := 0;

  if ParamCount < 3 then
  begin
    MessageBox(0,
      PChar(Format('%s: This program requires three command-line arguments.',
        [ExtractFileName(ParamStr(0))])),
      PChar(ExtractFileName(ParamStr(0))),
      MB_ICONERROR);
    Exit;
  end;

  if FileExists(ParamStr(PARAM_FILE_NAME)) then
    DeleteFile(PChar(ParamStr(PARAM_FILE_NAME)));

  if DownloadFile(ParamStr(PARAM_USER_AGENT), ParamStr(PARAM_URL),
      ParamStr(PARAM_FILE_NAME)) then
    ExitCode := 1;

end.
```

This program takes three command-line arguments: the UserAgent to be sent to the web server (can be anything, such as "MyApp Setup Utility"), the URL of the file on the Internet, and the file name of the file that is being created. Don't forget to enclose the arguments inside quotation marks ("). The exit code of the program is 0 if the download failed, and 1 if the download succeeded.

Then, in your Inno Setup script, you can do

```
[Files]
Source: "dwnld.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

function InitializeSetup: boolean;
var
  ResultCode: integer;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('dwnld.exe');
  if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dwnld.exe'),
      ExpandConstant('"{AppName} Setup Utility" "http://privat.rejbrand.se/sample.bmp" "{tmp}\bg.bmp"'),
      '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    if ResultCode = 1 then    
      (* Now you can do something with the file ExpandConstant('{tmp}\bg.bmp') *);
end;
```

Unfortunately, however, I know of no means by which you can change the `WizardImageFile` during runtime...

Answer (score 0):

Inno setup doesnt have any inbuilt functions for this, however, you can perform this action using batch files that do the job for you.

1) download a command line URL resource downloader like - 
http://www.chami.com/free/url2file_wincon.html

Some tips on how to use it - 
http://www.chami.com/tips/windows/062598W.html

2) Package it in your installer

3) create a batch file that calls url2file.exe and fetches your image into the app directory

4) Call this batch file in the initialize setup command of Inno Setup installer script.

5) Use that image wherever you want!

ps - If you are using the image in the setup, check if differed image loading is allowed or not.. i am not sure about that.
Let me know if you have any other questions